# WordPress cPanel html directory not found

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cpanel, web-hosting

So I engage with a website developer but due to lack of support decided to try doing it myself.
They provide with login details to cPanel and dewaweb wordpress manager and what I need is to edit some text of the website homepage.

However i couldn't find the page html file where i should do the editing in public_html. All i can see is the php and image files. the Wordpress manager also only shows media editing and does not have text/html edit function.

What should I do? i wonder if it's something to do with permission or if it's my unfamiliarity with Wordpress.
I'm new to Wordpress, cPanel and web hosting in general. Used hostgator before but it was more straightforward than this.

[cPanel File Manager Public_html does not have .html file][1]
[dewaweb wordpress manager only showing media, no text editing][2]

Comment: Wordpress generates content from the database, so there is no really such thing as homepage there... With some "buts" of course. Most content is coming from the database, so you need to login to WordPress admin (/wp-admin/) and try to edit content from there first. If what you want to edit is not pare of page content editable in admin but part of theme files, you may be lucky to find it and edit it under theme files (wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/), but before you start touching any files, you need to learn more about how WordPress works and try to get content changed in WP admin.

Comment: Hi @AndreiFilonov you're right. turns out that the text is part of theme files. I managed to edit the theme php file directly from cPanel edit.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when/if you update theme it may overwrite your edits, so need to be careful about those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you well you need to edit your site, you should edit it inside the Wordpress. not through a cPanel. Wordpress has its own builder and you don't actually need to edit HTML files by your self. Try asking for login info to your wp installation and edit needed page there.

Hope it helps and correct me if I'm wrong